# GitLab CI/CD Maven SpringBoot upload *jar error: No such file or directory

Tags: spring-boot, maven, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup a Springboot monorepo GitLab Pipeline, but the artifacts couldn#t be found.

mvn job

```
maven-package:
  stage: package
  inherit:
    default: true
    variables: true
  script:
    - cd springboot
    - mvn clean package -P dev
    - cd target
    - ls -al
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - springboot.jar
  tags:
    - docker
```

Job Log

```
$ cd target
$ ls -al
total 41124
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 classes
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 generated-sources
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 generated-test-sources
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 maven-archiver
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 maven-status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42053990 Jun 25 11:53 springboot.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    13258 Jun 25 11:53 springboot.jar.original
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 surefire-reports
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jun 25 11:53 test-classes
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: springboot.jar: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:latest
MAINTAINER vdoma.de
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/springboot.jar  app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Docker build fail because the artifacts could not have been found

Docker log error

```
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat target/springboot.jar: file does not exist
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Artifacts paths are from the root of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```yaml
maven-package:
  stage: package
  inherit:
    default: true
    variables: true
  script:
    - cd springboot
    - mvn clean package -P dev
    - cd target
    - ls -al
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - springboot/target/springboot.jar
  tags:
    - docker
```

```
FROM openjdk:latest
MAINTAINER vdoma.de
VOLUME /tmp
COPY springboot/target/springboot.jar  app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```